# Did a CSS/SCSS framework generate this file structure? If so, which one?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm a FE dev who just inherited a very large ReactJS/Gatsby project that has the following files in ./src/scss/

```
_base.fonts.scss
_base.forms.scss
_base.headings.scss
_base.links.scss
_base.lists.scss
_base.main.scss
_base.media.scss
_base.tables.scss
_base.text.scss
_generic.reset.scss
_layout.grids.scss
_layout.wrappers.scss
_modifier.animations.scss
_modifier.colors.scss
_modifier.display.scss
_modifier.spacing.scss
_module.article.scss
_module.footer.scss
_module.header.scss
_module.main.scss
_objects.blocks.scss
_objects.buttons.scss
_objects.cards.scss
_objects.forms.scss
_objects.icons.scss
_objects.images.scss
_objects.lists.scss
_objects.messaging.scss
_objects.navs.scss
_objects.search.scss
_objects.sections.scss
_objects.text.scss
_settings.variables.scss
_tools.include-media.scss
_tools.mixins.scss
_tools.mq-tests.scss
_tools.sg-updates.scss
_trumps.helper-classes.scss
_vendor.animate.scss
_vendor.modal-video.scss
_vendor.sal.scss
_vendor.slick.scss
main.scss
styleguide.min.scss
```

The guy who built and maintained this project was terminated today, and this project was dumped on me. The React project I've been working with for the last few years doesn't use SCSS at all, and I have very little time to ramp up on this; I have maintenance tickets that are due in just a couple of days.

Is this a framework? If so, I need to find documentation so I can quickly get up to speed.

For example, one of the first tickets I have is changing the content of this `<Section` from `justify-content: center` to `justify-content: flex-start`. Easy enough, but with all of these classes, I want to make sure I'm making the change correctly so that I don't jig something up.

`<Section className="c-hero__header c-hero__header--resources u-padding--quad--top u-space--quad--bottom u-padding--section u-box-shadow"> ... </Section>`

Edited to add: Here are the dependencies from package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^4.9.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "fs-readdir-recursive": "^1.1.0",
    "gatsby": "^3.6.2",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-preact": "^5.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-canonical-urls": "^1.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images-contentful": "^4.3.0",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^5.6.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^4.3.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.6.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sqip": "^3.6.0",
    "html-to-article-json": "^1.20.1",
    "instantsearch.css": "^7.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "onscroll-effect": "^1.3.1",
    "preact": "^10.5.13",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.1.19",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.5",
    "react-cookie-banner": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-inline-script": "^1.2.0",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.11.0",
    "react-lazysizes": "^1.0.0",
    "react-load-script": "0.0.6",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.7",
    "react-plx": "^1.3.17",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
    "react-scroll-toggle": "^1.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-structured-data": "0.0.14",
    "react-text-loop": "^2.3.0",
    "sal.js": "^0.8.5",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4"
  }
```

If someone can just point me to a framework, I can do the rest. Thanks!

Comment: The underscore at the beginning of the file name means it's  intended to be used as a "partial". Thus, I believe all of these files are imported individually inside the `main.scss`. As a developer, it is a common practice to create individual files for things you deem might be removed later on, so you'll only need to delete the files and remove their import statement. This might just be a human practice rather than any specific framework result.

Comment: Yes, all of these are imported in `main.scss`. Here's what `main.scss` looks like:
`/**
 * CONTENTS
 *
 * SETTINGS
 * Variables............Globally-available variables and config.
 *
 * TOOLS
 * Mixins...............Useful mixins.
 * Include Media........Sass library for writing CSS media queries.
 * Media Query Test.....Displays the current breakport you're in.
...
/*------------------------------------*\
    $GENERIC
\*------------------------------------*/
@import 'generic.reset';`
It doesn't look to me like something our previous dev made.

Comment: My mini-markdown skills failed. My point was:  `main.scss` is very meticulously structured, with a huge commented section of `CONTENTS` with subheadings: `SETTINGS`, `TOOLS`, `GENERIC` etc. It just doesn't look to me like something our previous dev made (he was a bit scatterbrained), which led me to believe he built the site using some pre-made framework or scaffolding.

Comment: @callan That's just standard SCSS practices. Doesn't look to be generated at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get help from others, you should give some details about your project. You did not mentioned whether any third party plugins have been used. At least you need to look up your `package.json` file to find out dependancy or share it to let others get to know the detail.

Comment: I just added the dependencies to the orig post.

Comment: To get to know which plugin is used by the `gatsby`, you need to look for `gatsby-config.js`, too.

Comment: Gatsby's plugins from `gatsy-config.js` are:
gatsby-plugin-react-helmet,
gatsby-plugin-preact,
gatsby-plugin-sass,
gatsby-plugin-sharp,
gatbsy-transformer-sharp,
gatsby-transformer-remark,
gatsby-remark-lazy-load

Comment: Hmm, seems like previous developer used css files from other projects. The only help I can give you now is just guessing. `_base.headings.scss`, `_module.header.scss`, `_objects.navs.scss` files. Those can be related to the heading styles. P.S. search classes with `c-hero__header`.